# Why is my duplicated mesh acting goofy?

Tags: rendering, mesh

[image: Duplicates distorted]

I made a tooth in edit mode. When I tried to duplicate it and modify for the other teeth, they look right in edit mode, but when I display the rendered preview, they are out of place and enlarged. How can I fix this?

Edit: It isn't the render that is causing the problem. The same thing appears in object mode in the other views also.
Additional edit: After I turned Blender off and back on, I saw a whole rainbow of teeth. Some kind of cyclic dependency or something?

[image]

[image: Rainbow of teeth]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured it out. It has to do with the shape keys I was experimenting with. I had a shape key assigned to the jaw to make the mouth move. Apparently attaching the teeth to the jaw after the key was assigned is not a good practice. I believe that's what led to the teeth expanding and moving out of place. I am going to remove that shape key, create the teeth, and then redo the shape key. If that doesn't fix things, I'll be back!